# How to expand widgets with window resize?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, resize, widget

I have a simple qt application with a `QTabWidget` inside the main window. I also have a few `QPushButton`(s) and `QRadioButton`(s).

What I want is that when I resize the window either manually or by maximizing/minimizing it should resize the containers in the same way.
In other words, what I want is equivalent of `DockStyle.Fill` in qt C++

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 13):

In Qt you have to use [**Layouts**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/layout.html):

> *The Qt layout system provides a simple and powerful way of automatically arranging child widgets within a widget to ensure that
> they make good use of the available space.*

In short, all components in a layout will be relocated to new places after the window, to which the layout belongs, is resized.

---

### If you are using deisgner:

#### 1. Click the empty space of a widget to select itself(or a main Window, I use just a base widget here for demonstration), and the layout option will be hightlighted:

[image]

#### 2. Choose a desired layout

Here is what object monitor looks like after a `QVBoxLayout` is used:

[image]

If your widget doesn't use layout, it will look like this:

[image]

What we have done here is to make the base widget/mainWindow equip a main layout. You can see that the buttons are automatically aligned, when you resize the widget, those component will be relocated according to the layout:

[image]

Perhaps you will find it nettlesome of those expanding space, so the next move is to add a [**Spacer**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSpacerItem.html) to the layout; so when layout is resized, only the spacer will stretch.
(Another option is to make your widgets expandable, see ** at the end of this post)

[image]

#### 3. Besides, you can add a layout into another to create a nested layout

For example, first I choose A and B (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) and use `QVBoxLayout`. This additional layout is not base layout and hence highlighted by red rectangle.

[image]

Then I choose C and the layout which contains A & B, and use `QHBoxLayout` on them,
[image]

Finally I use another `QVBoxLayout` as my main layout on the base widget, just like what we did previously.

[image]

And the object monitor:

[image]

---

### If you like the special feeling of hitting keyboard and always handcraft the code:

For the last example:

```
QWidget *Form = new QWidget;
QPushButton *pushButton_A = new QPushButton("A");
QPushButton *pushButton_B = new QPushButton("B");
QPushButton *pushButton_C = new QPushButton("C");

QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout; 
QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

verticalLayout->addWidget(pushButton_A);
verticalLayout->addWidget(pushButton_B);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(pushButton_C);
horizontalLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout);
mainLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout);

Form->setLayout(mainLayout);
Form->show();
```

---

### In your case

Here is an example of layout:

[image]

Notice that `QMainWidget` has a **centralwidget** as a base widget. Besides, each tab of `QTabWidget` has it's own base widget (**tab** and **tab_2** in the picture) which adopts another base layout.

---

*Don't forget to add [**Spacer**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSpacerItem.html#details) in layouts to shape them as you like.

** You can set [**size policy**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#details) on each widget (`QTabWidget`, `QPushButton` etc) to make them horizontally/vertically expandable or fixed, this cooperates with the layout strategy. For example, in the very begin example if we set

- button A to be vertically fixed, horizontally expanding
- button B to be vertically expanding, horizontally expanding
- button C to be vertically expanding, horizontally fixed

It will look like this when resizing:

[image]

Comment: I think you slightly switched "horizontally" and "vertically" in your explanations in the ** appendix

Answer (score 0):

you need to look into how to use layouts in your application

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

As a quick and simple first try, in the Designer you can right-click on the main window, and choose "layout" from the drop-down menu. Here you can pick the grid layout, for instance.