# resizable window in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm following an old online training about QT, the trainer seams no longer reachable, so maybe someone here can enlight me, in this training a small graphical window is made to draw figures. there is an area for buttons (to chose shapes) and an area to draw. Now in the course, he's able to resize the main form, and when he does, those area's resize with it. I followed course exactly but something is missing in this course because I don't get that behavior. I'd like to know what I should do to get such behavior using QTcreator (v4.71),

I include my code of the .ui file below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>MainWindow</class>
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>417</width>
<height>440</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>Main Window</string>
</property>
<widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
<widget class="QWidget" name="">
<property name="geometry">
 <rect>
  <x>20</x>
  <y>30</y>
  <width>381</width>
  <height>381</height>
  </rect>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
  <item>
  <widget class="RenderArea" name="renderArea" native="true">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnAstroid">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Astroid</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnCycloid">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Cycloid</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnHuygens">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Huygens</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnHypo">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Hypo Cycloid</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    </layout>
    </widget>
    </item>
    </layout>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  </widget>
  <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
  <customwidgets>
   <customwidget>
   <class>RenderArea</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>renderarea.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
   </customwidget>
  </customwidgets>
  <resources/>
  <connections/>
 </ui>
```

Comment: Thats not a copy paste from an instructor, its my .ui code but something seams missing. The problem is the instructor used keystrokes that dont work in QT-creator, and been trying 2 days to do it like he did, but it realy seams impossible maybe he uses Mac and i windows, but still resizing should be possible..but how?

Comment: You have a widget inside central widget without any layouts. So it works as it should be - without resizing client area. So, please don't write that you did "exactly the same". Thats why such questions are not welcome on stackoverflow.

Comment: I did the same as the video teacher did, but his shortcuts inside QT-creator did not work, i have to do this without keyboard interaction he used. Its not that i dont know coding its just QT-creator thats bugging me

Comment: Thanks your a great help, i hope someone else might actually know the answer.
Always nice how active forums help the newbies around.

Comment: No one could know the answer, since you did not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the cause should be visible in the ui file, its Qt markup language

Comment: Ha I found someone wiser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167180/how-to-expand-widgets-with-window-resize?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding the grid propery to them main form.
A small icon on top, when selected ctrl+g 
as in [How to expand widgets with window resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167180/how-to-expand-widgets-with-window-resize?rq=1)